How to re-add cloud status "Removed" songs with Windows Apple Music?
In the old Windows iTunes, the "Add to iCloud Music Library" option allowed us to re-add cloud "Removed" songs.

How can we achieve the same thing with Apple Music? Specifically, I found that "Add to Library" doesn't work. I don't want to delete the song locally and add it back because the metadata will be lost.


In my experiment, "Add to Library" is broken on the Windows Apple Music app. It cannot re-add songs with a cloud status of "Removed." However, the macOS Music app handles this as expected using "Add to Library."
